# Running XAMPP on network with IIS installed Windows Server

Tags: iis, xampp, localhost, windows-server-2008, lan

I recently installed Windows server 2016 essentials on to one of my system which behaves as a server (let's call this as SYSTEM-1). That is connected to 3-4 systems on LAN.

On SYSTEM-1 @ 192.168.1.2 - had IIS as default (port 80), and now I installed XAMPP (port 8080)

on SYSTEM-1 @ 192.168.1.2

- http://localhost -> opens IIS
- http://localhost:8080 -> opens XAMPP

on SYSTEM-2 / SYSTEM-3 / SYSTEM-4 @ 192.168.1.3/4/5

- http://192.168.1.2 -> opens IIS from SYSTEM-1
- http://192.168.1.2:8080 -> opens nothing

Apart from this I also want to access XAMPP (i.e on SYSTEM-1) from the internet

I tried for days to get this work. None of my searches helped me. Please help me and save my butt.

Comment: Your question is unclear - what is your actual issue? Both "URLs" using port 8080 are identical, once you claim everything works, once you claim you get an error...

Comment: I want both IIS and XAMPP works from LAN connected systems

Comment: That was just a repetition of what you already said. You did not at all respond to my question. May I ask why not? Sorry, but we cannot help if you do not answer and do not provide more precise information.

Comment: System A @ 192.168.1.2: has IIS and XAMPP installed, localhost - IIS, localhost:8080 - XAMPP

On System B @ 192.168.1.3: when I try 192.168.1.2 it displays IIS that is on SystemA. I want XAMPP of SystemA to show up.. How to do it??

Comment: IIS is using 80, and XAMPP is using 8080.

Comment: Either by moving IIS to another port so that you can move apache to port 80, or by implementing an internal proxy that maps the apache service into the IIS service, typically under some base path or based on some virtual host. Question still is what exactly you want.

Comment: I want IIS work on System A & System B- That is working;
I want XAMPP to work on System A & System B - It works on System A and not on System B

Comment: I assume with "working on System B" you mean that it is reachable,not that it is locally installed, right? If so it _might_ be that you are just looking for `http://192.168.1.2:8080/` (port 8080 has to be opened if system A has a local firewall) or, if you do _not_ want to specify a port number there, to use one of the approaches I described above.

Comment: I looked at firewall and it is open

Comment: And I assume you want to say that a request to `http://192.168.1.2:8080/` does not deliver the desired result? Don't have me drag everything out of you... Then most likely the apache http server does not bind to the IP address `192.168.1.2`, but only to the loopback address `127.0.0.1`. You have to change the configuration of the http server, most likely a `VirtualHost` directive. But for that to be certain we have to take a look at your http servers configuration. Please post the relevant sections inline in your question above. Thanks.